# What is the best way to add wrapper to a div using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hello i am trying to `add a wrapper class "wrprcls"` to the below html
Below is the html -

```
<span aria-current="page" class="page-numbers current">1</span>
    <a class="page-numbers" href="google.com;paged=2">2</a>
    <a class="page-numbers" href="google.com&amp;paged=2">2</a>
    <a class="next page-numbers" href="google.com;paged=2">Next »</a>
```

Desired -

```
<div class="wrprcls">
<span aria-current="page" class="page-numbers current">1</span>
        <a class="page-numbers" href="google.com;paged=2">2</a>
        <a class="page-numbers" href="google.com&amp;paged=2">2</a>
        <a class="next page-numbers" href="google.com;paged=2">Next »</a>
</div>
```

I have tried

```
jQuery( "span.page-numbers.current" ).wrap( "<div class='wrprcls'></div>" );
```

but it did not worked as desired.

Comment: `.wrap` is for wrapping a single element. Your `<span>` does not surround those `<a>` elements.

Comment: *"add wrapper to a `div`"* - code has 1 `span` and 3 `a` siblings, no divs - is there something else you're trying to do that you've not included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
jQuery(".page-numbers").wrapAll("<div class='wrprcls'></div>");
```

Demo - https://jsfiddle.net/vyspiansky/Lvqzkyj1/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this :

```js
$("span.page-numbers.current").siblings().addBack().wrapAll("<div class='wrprcls'></div>");
```

```css
.wrprcls { border: 1px solid pink }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span aria-current="page" class="page-numbers current">1</span>
<a class="page-numbers" href="google.com;paged=2">2</a>
<a class="page-numbers" href="google.com&amp;paged=2">2</a>
<a class="next page-numbers" href="google.com;paged=2">Next »</a>
```